# How to split uncode string into characters

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, unicode

I have strings like

```
"\U0aac\U0ab9\U0ac1\U0ab5\U0a9a\U0aa8",
"\U0a97\U0ac1\U0ab8\U0acd\U0ab8\U0acb",
"\U0aa6\U0abe\U0ab5\U0acb",
"\U0a96\U0a82\U0aa1"
```

But I want to split this strings by unicode character

I dont know hot to do. I know components seprated by function but it's no use here.
\nAny help would be apperiaciated

Comment: How are you obtaining these stings?

Comment: these are the gujarati word strings

Comment: I understand that part but are you typing them yourself or retrieving them from an API? As is the API is bad... You cannot have a string formatted that way.

Comment: What is a “character” here? Please give actual desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings you're getting really contain `\U` characters, you need to parse them manually and extract the unicode scalar values. Something like this:

```
let strings = [
    "\\U0aac\\U0ab9\\U0ac1\\U0ab5\\U0a9a\\U0aa8",
    "\\U0a97\\U0ac1\\U0ab8\\U0acd\\U0ab8\\U0acb",
    "\\U0aa6\\U0abe\\U0ab5\\U0acb",
    "\\U0a96\\U0a82\\U0aa1"
]

for str in strings {
    let chars = str.components(separatedBy: "\\U")
    var string = ""
    for ch in chars {
        if let val = Int(ch, radix: 16), let uni = Unicode.Scalar(val) {
            string.unicodeScalars.append(uni)
        }
    }
    print(string)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array, split its elements at non hexa digit values, compact map them into UInt32 values, initializate unicode scalars with them and map the resulting elements of your array into a UnicodeScalarView and init a new string with it:

```
let arr = [
    #"\U0aac\U0ab9\U0ac1\U0ab5\U0a9a\U0aa8"#,
    #"\U0a97\U0ac1\U0ab8\U0acd\U0ab8\U0acb"#,
    #"\U0aa6\U0abe\U0ab5\U0acb"#,
    #"\U0a96\U0a82\U0aa1"#]
```

---

```
let strings = arr.map {
    $0.split { !$0.isHexDigit }
    .compactMap { UInt32($0, radix: 16) }
    .compactMap(Unicode.Scalar.init)
}.map { String(String.UnicodeScalarView($0)) }

print(strings)
```

This will print

> ["બહુવચન", "ગુસ્સો", "દાવો", "ખંડ"]

Comment: But where is the part where we “split this strings by unicode character”?

Comment: @matt  if this is not what OP is trying to achieve I can simply delete my post but IMO he just don’t know how to express what he needs.

Comment: Could be true! I asked for example of desired output but no response. So we can’t be sure.

Answer (score -1):

So, the string that comes back already has the "\" because in order to use components you'd need to have an additional escaping "\" so that you'd be able to do:

```
var listofCodes = ["\\U0aac\\U0ab9\\U0ac1\\U0ab5\\U0a9a\\U0aa8", "\\U0aac\\U0ab9\\U0ac1\\U0ab5\\U0a9a\\U0aa8"]

var unicodeArray :[String] = []
listofCodes.forEach { string in

    unicodeArray
        .append(contentsOf: string.components(separatedBy: "\\"))
    unicodeArray.removeAll(where: {value in  value == ""})
}

print(unicodeArray)
```

I will revise this answer once you specify how you are obtaining these strings, as is I get a non-valid string error from the start.